# getActive()とgetActiveSpreadsheet()の違い

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

現在Google Apps scriptを使って色々作る勉強をしています。スプレッドシートでシートを操作とかしようとしているのですが、リファレンスを見て疑問があったので質問します。
SpreadsheetAppクラスにて、getActive()メソッドとgetActiveSpreadsheet()メソッドの説明が一字一句同じなので、これらのメソッドの違いがわかりません。特定条件下で異なる挙動があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

記憶では違いはないはずです。ただのエイリアスです。